# Armor on model doing weird stretching

Tags: modeling, rigging

I was following the tutorial for making a basic rpg character and armor for that character (video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzau6SFcNOk&t=665s). As I was going through it, I saw that my armor on the model was doing some weird stretching and I thought it might have something to do with weight painting and that helped a little bit but I am still having the stretching issue. Please let me know if you have any ideas to correct this issue.

**SEE THE FILE BELOW THE IMAGE FOR THE FILE THAT CONTAINS THE MODEL**

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry. I didn't save the original file with the leg armor problem but I ran into a similar situation with armor on the arm and have edited the post accordingly. I have also attached the file with the problem in question.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all apply the Mirror modifier, otherwise every change you make on a side will be mirrored on the other side.
- Try to correct the weight painting: Let your armature in *Pose* mode, in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Skeleton* > put it in *Rest* pose.
- Switch your coat mesh to *Weight Paint* mode, select a bone and try to correct its influence with a brush, move and rotate the bone to test the influence. Do the same thing for the body.
- To give some more precise corrections use the *Vertex Groups* assignments in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*.
- If you still see skin through the coat you can either: Use a *Mask* modifier to mask this part of the skin / delete this part of the skin mesh / use a *Mesh Deform* modifier as explained in these videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imhTnlKrTOY or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA

Comment: I've tried using the weight painting but it doesn't seem to fix the single vertex that's causing the problem then again I am still new to blender so I'm not sure if I am doing it wrong. I'll try to learn and figure out vertex groups and see if that will fix it. I'm curious as to how a few vertices even got to this point and why they are acting the way they are. So frustrating.